# ServiceReference Nightmares Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, service

I have a website that uses SL 4 to capture the webcam and a few other things.  I'm using ServiceReferences to services in the asp.net c# 4.0 website to provide access to data etc, which is described as the proper pattern.  Everything works great as Localhost.  BUT when I move the application (and xap) out to a hosted server, everything goes to hell.

I've looked at so many of the posts, but I can't figure it out.  I've tried to be sure that the references are correct, but anytime the servicereference points to the hosted server (and not localhost), i get a null reference as a retrun value from any asych call.

Help me before I go postal...

Comment: BTW-I do have the crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml, which I can browse to directly at the root of my website.

Comment: Are you logging any information at the service so you can see if it is the service crashing or the infrastructure? It could be as simple as an exception not being handled correctly in the service. Is the result empty AND the error as well?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm not logging, but I would imagine that if the service is working locally, that the code is sound.  It IS an assumption though.

Comment: There is not enough information to point you to solution. You can start with looking at the WCF tracing on server side as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx. If the traffic is not encrypted, looking at Fiddler tracing might also help. This could be as simple as incorrect server names or wrong authentication settings, but with this information you have to have psychic powers to guess the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I found this God-send of a post by Tim Heuer at http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/04/05/managing-service-references-in-silverlight-applications-for-different-environments.aspx, where he explains the strategies for multiple endpoints, and what fixed my issue...Relative endpoints.

Working now!